# Is a conformal mapping always (partially) differentiable over its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Consider a conformal mapping (whose domain and codomain may be either subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or of $\mathbb{C}^n$).

1. I wonder if it is always differentiable over its
   domain?
2. Is it always partially differentiable over its domain?

My questions comes from the following quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map), which seems assume the answers to the above questions true:

> The conformal property may be described in terms of the Jacobian
> derivative matrix of a coordinate transformation. If the Jacobian
> matrix of the transformation is everywhere a scalar times a rotation
> matrix, then the transformation is conformal.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: How do you define conformality for a map which isn't differentiable? The definition I know is that it preserves angles between tangent vectors, which requires first that it maps tangent vectors to tangent vectors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks! I didn't know that. But now I know. Thank you!